# nullpointer when using shared prefference in no activity class

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences

so i am trying to use my shared prefference in a no activity class but i keep getting null pointer on my

> private SharedPreferences setingPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Settings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

how do i solve this?

```
 public class ConnectionClass
{
    Context context;
    private SharedPreferences setingPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Settings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String ip;
    String classs = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    String db = "ISTABLocalDB";
    String un = "istab_wpf";
    String password = "istab_!234";
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection CONN() {
        ip = setingPreferences.getString("server", "");
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection conn = null;
        String ConnURL = null;
        try {
            Class.forName(classs);
            ConnURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ";"
                    + "databaseName=" + db + ";user=" + un + ";password="
                    + password + ";";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        }
        return conn;
```

Comment: can you post full class

Comment: how can that be a duplicate? as this is a nullpointer caused by a not initailized context to my sharedprefference and that one is just more a general question so is not helpfull at all and iknow what a nullpointer is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize your context variable. One way would be to pass the context variable from the activity class to this non-activity class by defining a constructor in the ConnectionClass

```
public ConnectionClass (Context context)  
{
   this.context = context;

}
```

Wherever you are going to instantiate this class, instantiate it by passing the context from the calling class.

For example, if you are instantiating this from an activity class, you can do so by

```
ConnectionClass conn = new ConnectionClass(MyActivity.this.getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: so if i change out my `public class ConnectionClass { 
` to `public ConnectionClass (Context context)  
{
   this.context = context;

} `

then i get class or interface expected

Comment: Class is fine as it is, just add the constructor method to it. Then you can pass along the context variable to be assigned to your in-class context variable, thereby avoiding the null pointer exception.

Comment: awesome that did the trick

Comment: Happy to help you out :)

Answer (score 2):

You are using context before initializing it. In you class constructor take context as argument and then initialize you preference Object.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize context.

Get the context on the constructor like this:

```
Context context;
private SharedPreferences setingPreferences;

public ConnectionClass(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

public Connection CONN() {
    setingPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Settings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ip = setingPreferences.getString("server", "");

    ...
```

Or you can get context direct on the method that you're calling:

```
private SharedPreferences setingPreferences;

public Connection CONN(Context context) {
    setingPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Settings", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ip = setingPreferences.getString("server", "");

    ...
```

Comment: that are giving me 
Error:(427, 53) error: method CONN in class ConnectionClass cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: I think you're not passing the parameter when you call CONN(), or you're passing a different type.

You have to call like this: Connection c = connectionClass.CONN(context);

You're calling the method in a activity class?

Comment: i getting Error:(427, 53) error: method CONN in class ConnectionClass cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
on `try {
                    Connection c = connectionClass.CONN‌​(context);
                    if (con == null) {` 
              and it cannot resolve method and symbol

Comment: Well, this can be a lot of things, but I'll try to help. First, you need to have a context, if you're calling in a activity class you can pass like this: Context context = this; if you're not in a activity class you have to get in another way. 
Second, I think you're using wrong variable names, "c" and "con" is the same thing, isn't? If is you have to rename c to con or con to c.
If the error persists tell me what IDE you're using and update the question with the code of the class that is calling the method CONN.